# Cucumber JS: How to export/update global variable outside Given/When/Then step?

Tags: javascript, cucumberjs

I try to update/export global variable (firstString) to use and validate it in 'Then' step.
How do I export it correctly? When I'm doing it this way, the firstString is undefined.
It works only when I export/import it inside steps. How can I update it globally and use it in 'Then' file?

helpers.js:

```
let firstString;
```

given.js:

```
let { firstString } = require('./helpers')

Given('I have first {string}', function (stringValue) {
    return stringRequest(stringValue).then(response => {
        firstString = response
    });
});

module.exports = { firstString }
```

then.js:

```
firstString = require('./helpers').firstString
Then('blablabla {string}', function (stringType) {
    console.log(firstString)
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I am correct in understanding what you want to do you are wanting to store data across steps. Todo that you will want to use the world instance that cucumber provides for you. You can access the world instance in steps via the `this` keyword.

So what you would do is

```
Given('I have first {string}', function (stringValue) {
return stringRequest(stringValue).then(response => {
    this.firstString = response
});
```

});

```
Then('blablabla {string}', function (stringType) {
    console.log(this.firstString)
});
```

For more information on the world instance check out https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/world.md

Comment: I've been adding it in my world function with the "this." prefix.

Comment: @HuckleberryCarignan yes that is the solution proposed in this answer. Please upvote if you believe the answer is correct